# How do I differentiate cos(1/(x-1)) from first principles?

Tags: derivatives

How do I differentiate $\cos(1/(x-1))$ from first principles?

I understand how to differentiate $\cos(x)$ from first principles. But I don't know how to do this for $\cos(1/(x-1))$ beyond the first couple steps.

Comment: What do you mean "from first principles"? If you mean by using the definition of the derivative (using limits), I believe the task would be almost impossible. That is why we prove theorems that help us simplify the matter.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Applying the [prosthaphaeresis Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)

$$\cos(a)-\cos(b)=-2\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$

with $a=\frac{1}{x+h-1}$ and $b=\frac{1}{x-1}$ along with the inequalities $|\sin(x)|\le 1$ and $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\left|\cos(a)-\cos(b)\right|&=\left|\cos\left(\frac{1}{x+h-1}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x+h-1}\right)\right|\\\\
&=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x+h/2-1}{(x+h-1)(x-1)}\right)\sin\left(\frac{h}{2(x+h-1)(x-1)}\right)\right|\\\\
&\le \left|\frac{h}{(x+h-1)(x-1)} \right|
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Viola did, using
$$\cos(p)-\cos(q)=-2\sin \left(\frac{p-q}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)$$ with 
$$p=\frac{1}{x-1+h}\qquad \text{and}\qquad q=\frac{1}{x-1}$$ we end with
$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1+h}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=2 \sin \left(\frac{h}{2 (x-1) (x-1+h)}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{2(x-1)+h}{2(x-1) (x-1+h)}\right)$$ Since $h$ is small
$$\sin \left(\frac{h}{2 (x-1) (x-1+h)}\right)\sim \frac{h}{2 (x-1) (x-1+h)}\sim \frac{h}{2 (x-1)^2 } $$
$$\sin
   \left(\frac{2(x-1)+h}{2(x-1) (x-1+h)}\right)\sim \sin
   \left(\frac{2(x-1)}{2(x-1) (x-1)}\right)=\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{x-1 }\right)$$ making by the end
$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1+h}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) } {h}\sim 2\times \frac 1 h\times\frac{h}{2 (x-1)^2 }\times\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{x-1 }\right)=\frac{\sin
   \left(\frac{1}{x-1 }\right)}{ (x-1)^2 }$$